# How to differentiate a composite function which includes unknown functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differentials

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\Phi$ be the function from $(0, \infty) \times [0, \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\Phi(r, \theta, \phi) = (r \sin \theta \cos \phi, r \sin \theta \sin \phi, r \cos \theta)$.

I want to compute $\frac{\partial f \circ\Phi}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial f \circ\Phi}{\partial \theta}$, $\frac{\partial f \circ\Phi}{\partial \phi}$.

How to compute this?

Comment: `Grad[f@\[CapitalPhi][r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much. It worked for me.

Comment: tchappy, posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: @kglr Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Φ[r_, θ_, ϕ_] := {r Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], r Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], r Cos[θ]}

grad = Grad[f@Φ[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}] 

TeXForm @ Style[grad, TextAlignment -> Left]
```

> $\scriptsize\left\{\cos (\theta ) f^{(\{0,0,1\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r
>    \cos (\theta )\})+\\ \ \ \ \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ) f^{(\{0,1,0\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r
>    \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta )\})+\\ \ \ \ \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ) f^{(\{1,0,0\})}(\{r
>    \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta )\}),\\ -r \sin (\theta )
>    f^{(\{0,0,1\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta
>    )\})+\\ \ \ \ r \cos (\theta ) \sin (\phi ) f^{(\{0,1,0\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta
>    ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta )\})+\\ \ \ \ r \cos (\theta ) \cos (\phi ) f^{(\{1,0,0\})}(\{r \sin (\theta
>    ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta )\}),\\r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi )
>    f^{(\{0,1,0\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta
>    )\})-\\ \ \ \ r \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ) f^{(\{1,0,0\})}(\{r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ),r \sin (\theta
>    ) \sin (\phi ),r \cos (\theta )\})\right\}$